# NopCommerce Plugin Localization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, plugins, nopcommerce, nopcommerce-4.0

I am working on a NopCommerce website and have quite a bit of site-wide customization so I have created a plugin to handle it all but not sure on how to handle the localization. I see there are a couple of ways of updating the Localization strings, one way I have found is in the Plugin's Install() method:

```
this.AddOrUpdatePluginLocaleResource("Plugins.Payments.PayPalStandard.Fields.AdditionalFee", "Additional fee");
```

This looks like it only adds new resource strings for the plugin, is there a similar way to update the other resources via the Install() method like:

> Admin.Catalog.Products.List.DownloadPDF

I found that there is a way to export the entire language to a language_pack.xml file, would it be better to just create an entire language pack instead? Is there a way to add a new language pack from the plugins Install() method?

I guess I could simply open the language_pack.xml file and add each resource found using the `AddOrUpdatePluginLocaleResource`, I was hoping that there was a built-in way of doing this using NopCommernce functionality.

Thanks!

Comment: You can build a language pack and deliver it with your plugin. And then inside plugin admin area provide and update button where you use language service to import your pack (lile nopCommerce does it in language edit)

Answer (score 0):

As @Raphael suggested in a comment, provide a language pack along with plugin file to the end users, and give an option to upload required resource file within your plugin configuration page.

As per as I know, there is no inbuilt way to add language pack on plugin installation, but you can do some code on plugin install method to find language pack file(s) from plugin folder and install it, not quite sure, you can take reference of inbuilt methods.